# How do I unlock entries in Bestiary?

Tags: diablo-immortal

I cannot understand how can I unlock Bestiary entries. I've already level 22 and just reached Westmarch.

I can see Bestiary if I click on my character portrait, but my progress is 0/104, but I'm pretty sure I've already fought some elite monsters and bosses.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monsters drop **Monstrous Essence** and you need to **collect 10** of them *(as you can see on the top right you have 0/10)* and then you can use the **Horadric Altar** to redeem them for a new bestiary page.

Comment: Yep, I started to see them drop. Turns out it’s blocked by main story progression, you need to meet Akara to unlock the altar